# Swift Initializers and Class Inheritance

Tags: swift, inheritance

I just wanted to ask why does this code print out the quantity 1 even though the RecipeIngredient doesn't provide a default value:

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[Unnamed]")
    }
}

class RecipeIngredient: Food {
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int) {
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }
    override convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
}

class ShoppingListItem: RecipeIngredient {
    var purchased = false
    var description: String {
        var output = "\(quantity) x \(name)"
        output += purchased ? " ✔" : " ✘"
        return output
    }
}

let item = ShoppingListItem()
print(item.quantity)
```

Comment: Add a unique print statement to every `init` method you posted and then look at the resulting output to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @rmaddy Better yet, put in break points :)

Comment: @Alexander I am assuming a playground where you can't set breakpoints.

Comment: I did the print statement trick - I did that before asking this question here. But what I cannot wrap my head around is how the methods are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ShoppingListItem()` is shorthand for
- `ShoppingListItem.init()` (inherited from `Food) which calls
- `ShoppingListItem.init(name:)` (inherited `RecipeIngredient`) which calls
- `ShoppingListItem.init(name: name, quantity: 1)` (inherited `RecipeIngredient`)  which calls
- `ShoppingListItem.init(name: String, quantity: Int)` (inherited `RecipeIngredient`)  which ultimately sets quantity to 1

This is some pretty basic debugging. You should really look into how to use the [Xcode debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html).

Comment: Thanks but it is pretty weird this call stack. How can Food.init() call subclass's convenience method that takes one parameter that is not set anywhere?

Comment: @VojtaBöhm I used `Food.init()` to actually mean "`init()`  of `ShoppingListItem` which it obtains by inheriting from `Food`". So `ShoppingListItem()` is really `ShoppingListItem.init()` (inherited from `Food`), which calls `ShoppingListItem.init(name:)` (inherited from `RecipeIngredient`) and so on

Comment: I think it makes more sense now, thanks. But it still is a bit confusing.

Comment: @VojtaBöhm What is confusing?

Comment: @VojtaBöhm http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a12017f9d122214058beccb

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes. Cheers :]

Answer (score 1):

The default value is provided by the convenience initializer of `RecipeIngredient`.